# Language injection in intellij with @Query

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

Using intellij idea 2016-3.4, is it possible to inject a language based on a parameter? Consider this

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from Foo")
List<Foo> nativeQuery();

@Query(value = "select a from Foo a")
List<Foo> hqlQuery();
```

The first example is a native mySql query, so I'd like to inject mySql dialect, while the second one is a hql query, where I would like to inject  the hibernate query language.

Right now, if I inject a language in one of the both query strings, both change to that language injection.

Can I make idea understand the `nativeQuery` parameter in the `@Query` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes it's possible.

You can't to do it over **Language Injection** window.

[image]

But you can use **[language injection comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-language-injections.html#injection_comments)** or **[@Language annotation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-language-injections.html#language_annotation)**. Below I inject *MySQL* and *HTML* in the same annotation using comments:

[image]

To remove comment hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (OS X <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) and choose `Un-inject Language/Reference`.

Comment: In this case, every caller who want to use this annotation has to add `language` comment on the annotation. From the standpoint of api provider, Is there any way to provide language injected annotation?