# Intellij Idea plugin syntax highlight in annotation string

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my project I want to check fields class when create new object. I use annotation with one string field. String field must have simple java condition code.

```
@Contract("x != 0 && y != null")
public class Test {
   private int x;
   private String y;
}
```

I want to write IntelliJ Idea plugin to syntax highlight annotation string. How I can to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Might help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233501/language-injection-in-intellij-with-query

Comment: I correct understand I must to add: @Language("Java") in declaration @Contract. I try but this don't work.

Comment: String in annotation @Contract don't highlight syntax.

Comment: @Language("JAVA")
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Contract {
    String value();
}                                                                                                                                                     But don't work.

Comment: I did another. I add @Language to String value(); It work but write error - 'class' or 'interface' expected